Defining graphql queries.ts in /backend (server) or in /frontend?
Previously I had queries.ts in /backend and imported all those queries to components and pages, additionally to frontend tests. But after I started created tests using mocks for queries.ts, I got this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined"
Then I thought it is probably because I am using server-side code in frontend, so I moved queries.ts to frontend. And the error disappeared.
Is this the correct solution, or is there a better way?
Frontend queries.ts:
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_MONSTERS = gql`
  query GetMonsters($searchTerm: String, $offset: Int, $limit: Int, $types: [String!]) {
    monsters(searchTerm: $searchTerm, offset: $offset, limit: $limit, types: $types) {
      monsters {
        id
        name
        size
        type
        alignment
        hit_points
        image
      }
      totalMonsters
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_DUNGEON = gql`
  query GetUserDungeon($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      dungeonName
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_DUNGEON_NAME = gql`
  mutation UpdateDungeonName($userId: ID!, $dungeonName: String!) {
    updateDungeonName(userId: $userId, dungeonName: $dungeonName) {
      dungeonName
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_FAVORITES = gql`
  query GetUserFavorites($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
        name
        size
        type
        alignment
        hit_points
        image
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_FAVORITE_MONSTER = gql`
  mutation AddFavoriteMonster($userId: ID!, $monsterId: ID!) {
    addFavoriteMonster(userId: $userId, monsterId: $monsterId) {
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_FAVORITE_MONSTER = gql`
  mutation RemoveFavoriteMonster($userId: ID!, $monsterId: ID!) {
    removeFavoriteMonster(userId: $userId, monsterId: $monsterId) {
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_MONSTER_REVIEWS = gql`
  query GetMonsterReviews($monsterId: ID!) {
    monster(id: $monsterId) {
      reviews {
        id
        user {
          id
          userName
        }
        difficulty
        description
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation AddReview($monsterId: ID!, $review: ReviewInput!) {
    addReview(monsterId: $monsterId, review: $review) {
      reviews {
        user {
          id
          userName
        }
        difficulty
        description
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const DELETE_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation DeleteReview($monsterId: ID!, $reviewId: ID!) {
    deleteReview(monsterId: $monsterId, reviewId: $reviewId) {
      reviews {
        id
        user {
          id
          userName
        }
        difficulty
        description
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation UpdateReview($monsterId: ID!, $reviewId: ID!, $review: ReviewInput!) {
    updateReview(monsterId: $monsterId, reviewId: $reviewId, review: $review) {
      id
      user {
        id
        userName
      }
      difficulty
      description
      createdAt
    }
  }
`;

export const CHECK_USERNAME = gql`
  query checkUsername($userName: String!) {
    checkUsername(userName: $userName)
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_EQUIPMENT = gql`
  query GetUserEquipment($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        index
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_EQUIPMENT_TO_CHARACTER = gql`
  mutation AddEquipmentToCharacter($userId: ID!, $equipmentId: ID!) {
    addEquipmentToCharacter(userId: $userId, equipmentId: $equipmentId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        index
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_EQUIPMENT_FROM_CHARACTER = gql`
  mutation RemoveEquipmentFromCharacter($userId: ID!, $equipmentId: ID!) {
    removeEquipmentFromCharacter(userId: $userId, equipmentId: $equipmentId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        index
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_ALL_EQUIPMENTS = gql`
  mutation RemoveAllEquipments($userId: ID!) {
    removeAllEquipments(userId: $userId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser($userName: String!) {
    createUser(userName: $userName) {
      token
      user {
        id
        userName
        class {
          name
        }
        race {
          name
        }
        abilityScores
        equipments {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const LOGIN_USER = gql`
  mutation loginUser($userName: String!) {
    loginUser(userName: $userName) {
      token
      user {
        id
        userName
        class {
          name
        }
        race {
          name
        }
        abilityScores
        equipments {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
export const UPDATE_USER_CLASS = gql`
  mutation UpdateUserClass($userId: ID!, $classId: ID!) {
    updateUserClass(userId: $userId, classId: $classId) {
      id
      class {
        name
        index
        hit_die
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_ABILITY_SCORES = gql`
  mutation UpdateAbilityScores($userId: ID!, $scores: [Int!]!) {
    updateAbilityScores(userId: $userId, scores: $scores) {
      id
      abilityScores
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_CLASS = gql`
  query GetUserClass($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      class {
        id
        name
        index
        hit_die
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_ARRAY_SCORES = gql`
  query GetArrayScores($userId: ID!) {
    getArrayScores(userId: $userId)
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_USER_RACE = gql`
  mutation UpdateUserRace($userId: ID!, $raceId: ID!) {
    updateUserRace(userId: $userId, raceId: $raceId) {
      id
      race {
        name
        speed
        alignment
        size
        img
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_RACES = gql`
  query GetRaces($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    races(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
      races {
        id
        index
        name
        speed
        alignment
        size
        img
      }
      totalRaces
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_RACE = gql`
  query GetUserRace($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      id
      race {
        id
        name
        speed
        alignment
        size
        img
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_ABILITYSCORES = gql`
  query GetAbilityScores($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    abilities(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
      abilities {
        index
        name
        skills
      }
      totalAbilities
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_CLASSES = gql`
  query GetClasses($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    classes(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
      classes {
        id
        index
        name
        hit_die
        skills
      }
      totalClasses
    }
  }
`;


backend queries.ts
import { gql } from 'apollo-server';

export const GET_MONSTERS = gql`
  query GetMonsters($searchTerm: String, $offset: Int, $limit: Int, $types: [String!]) {
    monsters(searchTerm: $searchTerm, offset: $offset, limit: $limit, types: $types) {
      monsters {
        id
        name
        size
        type
        alignment
        hit_points
        image
      }
      totalMonsters
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_DUNGEON = gql`
  query GetUserDungeon($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      dungeonName
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_DUNGEON_NAME = gql`
  mutation UpdateDungeonName($userId: ID!, $dungeonName: String!) {
    updateDungeonName(userId: $userId, dungeonName: $dungeonName) {
      dungeonName
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_FAVORITES = gql`
  query GetUserFavorites($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
        name
        size
        type
        alignment
        hit_points
        image
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_FAVORITE_MONSTER = gql`
  mutation AddFavoriteMonster($userId: ID!, $monsterId: ID!) {
    addFavoriteMonster(userId: $userId, monsterId: $monsterId) {
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_FAVORITE_MONSTER = gql`
  mutation RemoveFavoriteMonster($userId: ID!, $monsterId: ID!) {
    removeFavoriteMonster(userId: $userId, monsterId: $monsterId) {
      favoritedMonsters {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_MONSTER_REVIEWS = gql`
  query GetMonsterReviews($monsterId: ID!) {
    monster(id: $monsterId) {
      reviews {
        id
        user {
          id
          userName
        }
        difficulty
        description
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation AddReview($monsterId: ID!, $review: ReviewInput!) {
    addReview(monsterId: $monsterId, review: $review) {
      reviews {
        user {
          id
          userName
        }
        difficulty
        description
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const DELETE_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation DeleteReview($monsterId: ID!, $reviewId: ID!) {
    deleteReview(monsterId: $monsterId, reviewId: $reviewId) {
      reviews {
        id
        user {
          id
          userName
        }
        difficulty
        description
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_REVIEW = gql`
  mutation UpdateReview($monsterId: ID!, $reviewId: ID!, $review: ReviewInput!) {
    updateReview(monsterId: $monsterId, reviewId: $reviewId, review: $review) {
      id
      user {
        id
        userName
      }
      difficulty
      description
      createdAt
    }
  }
`;

export const CHECK_USERNAME = gql`
  query checkUsername($userName: String!) {
    checkUsername(userName: $userName)
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_EQUIPMENT = gql`
  query GetUserEquipment($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        index
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const ADD_EQUIPMENT_TO_CHARACTER = gql`
  mutation AddEquipmentToCharacter($userId: ID!, $equipmentId: ID!) {
    addEquipmentToCharacter(userId: $userId, equipmentId: $equipmentId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        index
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_EQUIPMENT_FROM_CHARACTER = gql`
  mutation RemoveEquipmentFromCharacter($userId: ID!, $equipmentId: ID!) {
    removeEquipmentFromCharacter(userId: $userId, equipmentId: $equipmentId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        index
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const REMOVE_ALL_EQUIPMENTS = gql`
  mutation RemoveAllEquipments($userId: ID!) {
    removeAllEquipments(userId: $userId) {
      id
      equipments {
        id
        name
        category
        value
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser($userName: String!) {
    createUser(userName: $userName) {
      token
      user {
        id
        userName
        class {
          name
        }
        race {
          name
        }
        abilityScores
        equipments {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const LOGIN_USER = gql`
  mutation loginUser($userName: String!) {
    loginUser(userName: $userName) {
      token
      user {
        id
        userName
        class {
          name
        }
        race {
          name
        }
        abilityScores
        equipments {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
export const UPDATE_USER_CLASS = gql`
  mutation UpdateUserClass($userId: ID!, $classId: ID!) {
    updateUserClass(userId: $userId, classId: $classId) {
      id
      class {
        name
        index
        hit_die
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_ABILITY_SCORES = gql`
  mutation UpdateAbilityScores($userId: ID!, $scores: [Int!]!) {
    updateAbilityScores(userId: $userId, scores: $scores) {
      id
      abilityScores
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_CLASS = gql`
  query GetUserClass($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      class {
        id
        name
        index
        hit_die
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_ARRAY_SCORES = gql`
  query GetArrayScores($userId: ID!) {
    getArrayScores(userId: $userId)
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_USER_RACE = gql`
  mutation UpdateUserRace($userId: ID!, $raceId: ID!) {
    updateUserRace(userId: $userId, raceId: $raceId) {
      id
      race {
        name
        speed
        alignment
        size
        img
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_RACES = gql`
  query GetRaces($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    races(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
      races {
        id
        index
        name
        speed
        alignment
        size
        img
      }
      totalRaces
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_USER_RACE = gql`
  query GetUserRace($userId: ID!) {
    user(id: $userId) {
      id
      race {
        id
        name
        speed
        alignment
        size
        img
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_ABILITYSCORES = gql`
  query GetAbilityScores($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    abilities(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
      abilities {
        index
        name
        skills
      }
      totalAbilities
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_CLASSES = gql`
  query GetClasses($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
    classes(offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
      classes {
        id
        index
        name
        hit_die
        skills
      }
      totalClasses
    }
  }
`;


Sorry if this has been asked already, I tried reading in both Apollo server docs and graphql docs, but they did not specify where in project to have queries.ts code.
